# Multiple PUT endpoints vs single PUT endpoints to update entity attribute

Tags: api, rest, web-services

I have an API controller for an entity called Order which has as an attribute called Status which can take the following values: Pending, Cancelled, Production, Delivered.
I was wondering which would be the proper approach for updating such attribute.
Should i have PUT endpoints for each value of Status to update the attribute with only the id or should I have the typical REST PUT endpoint and just update the value according to a request body containing the object id and it's new Status value?

PS: I'm already managing the values internally as an enum so I don't have to worry about faulty input

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "multiple PUT methods", because there's only 1 PUT method. Do you mean multiple endpoints, multiple request bodies? Show some examples of the 2 approaches you're considering.

Comment: Updated the post to be more clear. I meant endpoints, my mistake, i'm sorry, English is not my first language

Answer (score 0):

A `PUT` operation *updates* some resource. If you are updating a 'status resource' to have a value, or if you are updating an 'order resource' to have a different status, I would expect a `PUT` or `PATCH` request on a resource like `/order/123` or `/order/123/status`.

Having a endpoint/resource per status makes no sense, because you are updating an order (with `PUT`), you are not updating the 'Pending status resource'.

Comment: I guess having multiple PATCH doesn't make sense either. What I wanted to do was to be able to update the Order Status without worrying about input other than the id in the request, and just call each different endpoint from the frontend like you would call a class method `/order/cancel/123` or `/order/pending/123`

Comment: Maybe it's not RESTful but I'm developing a solo project and wan't to make thing as easy as possible for when I have to wrok on the frontend. Is it worth it or am I setting up some meessy hard to mantain API?

Comment: Am I correct to understand that you feel it's difficult to add a status property in a request body? If so, why?